# How to add customized cell with images?

Tags: ios, xlform

i am very new to the xlform. I know there are already a lot of template cells. Is there an easy way to add the customized cell to the row? For example, i made usercell with images, and I want to add this cell to the first section. What is the better way to do that?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
XLFormDescriptor * form;
XLFormSectionDescriptor * section;
XLFormRowDescriptor * row;

form = [XLFormDescriptor formDescriptorWithTitle:@"Settings"];

// First section
section = [XLFormSectionDescriptor formSectionWithTitle:@"Account"];
[form addFormSection:section];

// User image
row = [[XLFormRowDescriptor alloc] init];
[section addFormRow:row];
// Is there  a way to hook the customized UserCell with row together here?
```

I have created a UserCell for this, but how can I add the customized cell into this row?

Any helps and suggestions are really appreciated.